# Using WebApiContrib.Core.Formatter.Csv in ASP.NET Core 3.0 Web API project

Tags: asp.net-core-3.0, web-api-contrib

I want to migrate the AddCsvSerializerFormatters configuration to .NET Core 3.0

[Taken from the example code here](https://github.com/WebApiContrib/WebAPIContrib.Core/blob/54baf031ed258962906c3483f3ab2b8c33081ba1/samples/WebApiContrib.Core.Samples/Startup.cs#L42)

```
services.AddMvc(o =>
    {
        ...
    })
    .AddCsvSerializerFormatters()
```

A .NET Core 3.0 web api project registers just the controllers, and registering all of Mvc seems overkill.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  services.AddControllers();
  ...
}
```

References:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#mvc-service-registration

Comment: Why not `services.AddControllers().AddCsvSerializerFormatters();`?

Comment: Thanks, I never thought of that...‍♂️ 
Turns out AddControllers implements IMvcBuilder which is the magic glue.

Can you add your reply as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ServiceCollection.AddControllers()` returns an `IMvcBuilder` type. Since this package adds an extension  `AddCsvSerializerFormatters()` for `IMvcBuilder`, you can chain the method invocation by:

```cs
services.AddControllers().AddCsvSerializerFormatters();
```

See [AddCsvSerializerFormatters()](https://github.com/WebApiContrib/WebAPIContrib.Core/blob/6f658194253fb14ef8fdb9b86e9ed1f1a6db5a8b/src/WebApiContrib.Core.Formatter.Csv/CsvFormatterMvcBuilderExtensions.cs#L9-L42):

```
public static IMvcBuilder AddCsvSerializerFormatters(this IMvcBuilder builder)
```